# Get previous route Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I created a little service where I can store the route changes.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouteState {

  private previousUrl: string;
  private currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {        
        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
      };
    });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl() {
    return this.previousUrl;
  }    
}
```

But everytime the route change the vars currentUrl and previousUrl are undefined. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you add to app.module providers list ? , everyting working 

Comment: Your code is works as you want in RouteState Service i think you made mistake either time of call your getPreviousUrl function or in other place. if provide your code then i can help you.

Comment: The problem is that everytime the route changed, the previousUrl was undefined. I  isn't saving the value.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use angular's Location service, it is inbuilt to angular and import it from '@angular/common' like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Hero }         from '../hero';
import { HeroService }  from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.css' ]
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }   
}
```

And then use **location.back()** to goto previous page. This is a working example:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvvrbgrmmda

Comment: This will not work if you have no history. For example if you opened the page in a new tab.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the previous route you can create an observable like this

```
 public previousRoute$: Observable<string> = this.router.events.pipe(
   filter((e) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
   pairwise(),
   map((e: [RoutesRecognized, RoutesRecognized]) => e[0].url)
 );
```

Now you can subscribe this observable and perform any action (Make sure you unsubscribe this observable on OnDestroy event.)

```
this.previousRoute$.subscribe(url => {
  //perform your action
});
```

NOTE: This observable will start emitting event when user is on 2nd navigation.

Comment: You should not use a getter to do this because Angular may call it multiples times and produce a memory leak. You should store it and unsubscribe it on component destroy lifecycle

Comment: If you subscribe it in OnInit hook then Angular will only call it once and as it returns infinite observable you need to unsubscribe it to avoid any memory leak that I already mentioned above in parentheses.

Comment: @VikashDahiya That's correct, but maybe other developers will use it not in the way it was meant to. The argument which @alexandre-rousseau came up with is pretty important, imho. Therefore I would just declare a field for it.


`private subscription: Subscription;
previousRoute$: Observable<string> = this.router.events.pipe(...);
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.previousRoute$.subscribe(...)
}`

Comment: @alexandre-rousseau and HasBert You are correct I have updated the answer. Returning observable from getter is not a good idea if we want to use that observable in html template (other scenario also possible) as it might call it multiple times which results into multiple subscription of same observable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to get you previous route using `@angular/router`

Find more on [the original post](https://betterprogramming.pub/previous-route-in-angular-6-484288410d99)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterEvent, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class PreviousRouteService {

    private previousUrl: string;
    private currentUrl: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) {

        this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
        this.previousUrl = null;

        this.router.events
                    .pipe(filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
                    .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
                        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
                        this.currentUrl = event.urlAfterRedirects;
                        console.log("prev: ", this.previousUrl)
                        console.log("curr: ", this.currentUrl)
                    });

    }

    public getPreviousUrl() {
        return this.previousUrl;
    }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to use the Location Service provided by Angular then you can try  out the following service.

```
// service to get prev route
@Injectable()
export class RouteBackService {
    public getPreviousUrl(routeArray): string {
        let prevRoute = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < routeArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (routeArray[i].url._value[0].length > 0) {
                prevRoute += routeArray[i].url._value[0].path + '/';
            } 
        }
        return prevRoute.slice(0, -1);
    }
}

// in the component from where you want to route back    
export class YourComponent {
    constructor (private _aRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                   private _routeBack: RouteBackService
                   private _router: Router) {}
    goBack() {
        const prevRoute=this._routeBack.getPreviousUrl(this._aRoute.pathFromRoot);
        this._router.navigate([prevRoute]);
    }
}
```